# How to loop dataframe column in databricks using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, user-defined-functions, azure-databricks, lemmatization

[image: i want to lemmatize a sentence as shown below.its working fine for single sentence as shown in the image]

[image: Referring this image i want to lemmatize the entire dataframe column of string but it throws error]

i want to apply lemmatization for dataframe column using pyspark running in databricks.Refer the images for error.

Answer (score 0):

Import the function lemmatize_sentence() in side the function and then create the UDF that should work.
you are getting this error because the import is on driver node not on the entire cluster.
when you import this inside the function so in that case while creating the UDF it will send the copy of function to all the nodes in the cluster.